# Словарь нужно отредактировать так, чтобы выводились символы после знака $

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, for, steam

Столкнулся с проблемой при парсинге вещей Staem:
В графе с ценой так же присутствует и количество вещей, они в HTML коде названы одинаково, а именно:

```html
<div class="market_commodity_order_summary" id="market_commodity_forsale">Лотов на продажу: <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">94380</span><br>Начальная цена: <span class="market_commodity_orders_header_promote">$1.29</span></div>
```

Мне нужна только их цена, тоесть 4 символа после знака $, через атрибут .find выдается только первое значение, тоесть количество вещей. Думаю сделать поиск через цикл for, но не знаю как написать код, чтобы после знака $ он выводил ещё 4 символа.
Мой код (воспользовался силениумом, так как без него, значения были пусты):

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import time

s = Service('C:\\Users\\Семен\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Python\\Parser\\geckodriver.exe')

def get_data(url):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'
    }

    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    with open('index.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(r.text)


def get_data_s(url):
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.set_preference('general.useragent.override', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36')

    #try:
    #    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    #       options = options
    #    )
    #    driver.get(url=url)
     #   time.sleep(2)
#
     #   with open('index_s.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
      #      file.write(driver.page_source)

    #except Exception as ex:
    #    print(ex)
    #finally:
    #    driver.close()
    #    driver.quit()
    with open('index_s.html', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        src = file.read()

    soup = bs(src, 'lxml')
    info = soup.find_all('div', class_="market_listing_iteminfo")
    names = []
    for name in info:
        names.append(
            {
                'Название: ': name.find('h1', class_='hover_item_name').text,
                'Цена покупки: ': name.findNext('div', class_='market_commodity_order_summary', ).text



            }
        )

    print(names)
def main():
    # get_data('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case')
    get_data_s('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться `.split()` вот в этой строке:

`'Цена покупки: ': price = name.findNext('div', class_='market_commodity_order_summary', ).text.split('$')`

А после вывести данные с помощью среза
`print(price[7:])`

В итоге, если у вас входные данные формата `Цена: $%Ваша цена$`

То вы сможете получить именно то, что вам нужно, вот пример кода:

```
price = 'Цена: $2.0'
print(price.split('$')[7:])
print(price[7:])
```

> Input: Цена: $2.0
>
> Output: 2.0

Comment: У меня 'Цена покупки' добавляется в словарь, а присваивать константу переменной name.find нельзя, как я понял, в любом случае у меня выдавало ошибку: `'Цена покупки: ': price = name.findNext('div', class_='market_commodity_order_summary', ).text.split('$')
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

```
'Цена покупки: ': name.findAll('span', class_='market_commodity_orders_header_promote')[1].text.replace('$','')
```

Comment: Спасибо, текст выдался, не знал что можно функции .findAll поставить условие, чтоб она выводила 2 результат поиска, вы очень помогли, а так мне знак доллара не мешал, поэтому функцией .replace не воспользовался, но теперь буду знать, спасибо!